Pulling issues using forge fails
I'm trying to pull issues/pulls across GitHub/GitLab and have read the instructions on configuring forge (and ghub for good measure).
I have generated Personal Access Tokens for both GitLab and GitHub (for both accounts I wish to use) and stored them in ~/.authinfo.gpg, it looks like...
machine haldane login root port su password ########
machine kimura login root port su password ########
machine gitlab.com/api/v4 login nshephard^forge password glpat-########
machine api.github.com login slackline^forge password ghp_########
machine api.github.com login ns-rse^forge password ghp_########

~/.gitconfig
Because I have different accounts on GitHub I have the following in ~/.gitconfig so that the SSH credentials used are conditional on the directory.
# GitHub Work
[includeIf "gitdir:~/work/git/hub/ns-rse/"]
    path = ~/dotfiles/git/.gitconfig_work
[includeIf "gitdir:/mnt/work/git/hub/ns-rse/"]
    path = ~/dotfiles/git/.gitconfig_work
# GitHub Personal
[includeIf "gitdir:~/work/git/hub/slackline/"]
    path = ~/dotfiles/git/.gitconfig_personal
[includeIf "gitdir:/mnt/work/git/hub/slackline/"]
    path = ~/dotfiles/git/.gitconfig_personal
# GitLab
[includeIf "gitdir:/mnt/work/git/lab/nshephard/"]
    path = ~/dotfiles/git/.gitconfig_personal
[includeIf "gitdir:/mnt/work/git/lab/"]
    path = ~/dotfiles/git/.gitconfig_personal

This way as per git-config docs all repositories  under the relevant directory include the additional configuration.
NB - I have the double entries as on one system ~/work/ is a mounted partition.
.github_work
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
[core]
    sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/haldane_ed25519 -F /dev/null
[github]
    user = "ns-rse"

.github_personal
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
[core]
    sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 -F /dev/null
[github]
    user = "slackline"
[gitlab]
    user = "nshephard"

The Problem
I use the exact same configuration across two computers (kimura and haldane) as they are .dotfiles and I have symlinks pointing to the relevant files for the configuration files.
❱ l .authinfo.gpg .gitconfig 
lrwxrwxrwx neil neil 37 B Sun Nov 28 08:58:53 2021  .authinfo.gpg ⇒ /home/neil/dotfiles/git/.authinfo.gpg
lrwxrwxrwx neil neil 23 B Mon Sep  3 20:04:41 2018  .gitconfig ⇒ dotfiles/git/.gitconfig

haldane
I can forge-pull against GitHub on my work repositories under ~/work/git/hub/ns-rse/ all is good, I can pull issues/pull requests, edit them, submit changes and things get updated.
If I try and forge-pull on my personal repositories under ~/work/git/hub/slackline/ (even after freshly cloning them!) I'm told...
Repository "slackline/pcc" does not exist on "api.github.com"
Maybe it was renamed and you have to update "remote.<remote>.url"?

If I try to forge-pull against GitLab on my repositories under ~/work/git/lab/nshephard/ nothing is picked up, no error messages though.
kimura
I can't forge-pull from either GitHub account nor GitLab from this computer with the exact same configuration.
If I try forge-pull against a work GitHub repository under ~/work/git/hub/ns-rse/
Required Github token ("ns-rse^forge" for "github.com") does not exist.
See https://magit.vc/manual/ghub/Getting-Started.html
or (info "(ghub)Getting Started") for instructions.
(The setup wizard no longer exists.)

If I try forge-pull against a personal GitHub repository under ~/work/git/hub/slackline/ I get a similar error, but with the slackline username
Required Github token ("slackline^forge" for "github.com") does not exist.
See https://magit.vc/manual/ghub/Getting-Started.html
or (info "(ghub)Getting Started") for instructions.
(The setup wizard no longer exists.)

If I try forge-pull against a GitLab repository I'm told
no oauth token found for gitlab.com/api/v4 account nshephard

...but it seems to go through a few cycles and does eventually pull things, I can edit and update issues/pull requests (albeit very slowly).
Questions
Things that I'm currently baffled about...

Why aren't the tokens for api.github.com recognised on the kimura system when it is on haldane?
Why aren't repositories recognised under https://github.com/slackline/ on haldane?
Why the error message about oauth against GitLab on kimura but it still appears to work?
Why doesn't the same token for GitLab work on haldane?

There is no doubt lots more information I could provide to help debug this but I'm unsure what that might be so please let me know if there is anything specific that would be useful.
